# Как правильно объединить две таблицы в запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно объединить две таблицы в одну результирующую, и чтобы в ней были только уникальные поля. Еще нужно вернуть в результате количество полей.

Пробую такой запрос:

```
(
    (SELECT * FROM user_send
        INNER JOIN todo ON (todo.id = user_send.id_todo AND user_send.id_user = $id_user)
        WHERE todo.confirm = 1
    )
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM task_send
        INNER JOIN todo t ON (t.id = task_send.id_todo AND task_send.id_user_to = $id_user)
        WHERE t.confirm = 1
    )
) AS nocount
```

Использую оператор `UNION` для объединения запросов, но получаю ошибку.

У меня есть одна таблица `todo`, c которой связаны две другие. Мне нужно получить все уникальные из `todo`, которые есть в тех двух таблицах.

Comment: Какую ошибку? И совпадают ли количество и типы столбцов в обоих `SELECT`'ах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мне нужно получить все уникальные из todo, которые есть в тех двух таблицах.

Ну так и пиши

```
SELECT * FROM todo
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM user_send WHERE ....)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM task_send WHERE ....)
```

Если процент записей, которые должны быть выведены - небольшой (в среднем случае меньше 10% от общего количества записей в todo) то можно попробовать другой способ

```
SELECT * FROM todo
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id_todo FROM user_send WHERE id_user = $id_user
  UNION 
  SELECT id_todo FROM task_send WHERE id_user_to = $id_user
)
```

если планировщик не сможет использовать индекс то IN заменить на INNER JOIN

Comment: не `AND`, а `OR`. И `...exists(select 1...` будет аккуратнее.

Comment: and/or - признаю, "есть в тех двух" прочитал как "есть в обеих". select */select 1 - тут без разницы. СУБД игнорирует список выборки, т.к. проверяется только наличие/отсутствие строк.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов  Да работает но производительность такого запроса очень низкая, во первых запрос делает перебор по всем строкам в таблице и анализируя через EXPLAINE  показало что запрос сложности - PRIMARY и ему приходиться проходить все строки таблици todo